# Undefined Values in Kendo Dropdownlist

Tags: telerik-mvc

> I am using Telerik's dropdownlist in my MVC application View. I am facing two problems:
>
> 1) When I run my application, I find every value of kendo dropdownlist is "Undefined".
>      This is the code for my View:

```
  @model IEnumerable<EulenMgrKendoUIMvcApplication.Dominio.Tablas.DelegacionProductoUsuario>

  @(Html.Kendo().DropDownListFor(d=>d)
        .Name("IdDelegacionProductoDrpDwn").HtmlAttributes(new { @style = "font-size:12px" })
        .DataTextField("IdDelegacionProducto")
        .DataValueField("IdDelegacionProducto")
        **.BindTo((System.Collections.IEnumerable)ViewData["IdDelegacionProducto"]))**
```

> This is my controller, where I populate the dropdownlist:

```
   public class DelegacionProductoUsuarioController : Controller
       public ViewResult List()
       {
            IEnumerable<DelegacionProductoUsuario> delegaciones = DelegacionProductoUsuario.GetAll();
            **PopulateDelegacionProducto();**
            return View(delegaciones);
       }
       private void PopulateDelegacionProducto()
       {
           List<Int64> IdDelegacionProductoList = new List<Int64>();
           foreach( DelegacionProductoUsuario d in DelegacionProductoUsuario.GetAll()){
              IdDelegacionProductoList.Add(d.IdDelegacionProducto);
           }
           ViewData["IdDelegacionProducto"] =IdDelegacionProductoList ;
      }
```

}

```
 >I am debugging the application and the controller is passing to the view the proper values,so I don't understand why it doesn't show them.
```

> 2) Second problem: I insert this Dropdownlist in one of the columns of a kendo grid with no success. 
>   In it's place it appears a common label. Here is the code for my Grid, I mark in Bold the column where I try to show  my dropdownList:

```
  @(Html.Kendo().Grid(Model)
      .Name("Grid")
      .Columns(columns=>
      {
        columns.Bound(d => d.BorradoLogico).Title("Borrado logico");
        columns.Bound(d => d.FTick).Title("Ftick");
       **columns.Bound(d => d.IdDelegacionProducto).Title("IdDelegacionProducto").EditorTemplateName("IdDelegacionProductoDrpDwn");**    
        columns.Bound(d => d.IdUsuario).Title("IdUsuario");
     })
```

Comment: http://questionbox.co.in/bind-kendo-ui-asp-net-mvc-dropdownlist/

Check this link. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

How does that 'DelegacionProductoUsuario' class look like? Does it have property named 'IdDelegacionProducto' ? It looks like you have not set the dataValueField correctly.

As for the second question, where did you put that EditorTemplate (is it in the Shared/EditorTemplate or in a EditorTemplates folder? More info about editor template can be found [here](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/using-kendo-with/aspnet-mvc/helpers/grid/editor-templates).

Answer (score 0):

Dear Petur: thanks a lot for answering. On regard to your answer:
  My class DelegacionProductoUsuario does have a property called IdDelegacionProducto. On regard to your question "where I place the EditorTemplate" , I don't understand what you mean, I place it in the view that Lists all of my DelegacionProductoUsuario . Please keep on helping me. Thanks a lot Petur.